# Enable a button only when the video is completed- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a video_player and chewie to play videos in this app. I need to enable a button to pop the page only when the video is completed playing if the video is still playing I want to button to be disabled. I used AbsorbPointer to enable and disable my button but that does not work.

```
widget.videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
          if (widget.videoPlayerController.value.position ==
              widget.videoPlayerController.value.duration) {
            print('video completed.');
          }
        });
```

The above code prints me the message after video has completed playing, but this does not help me enable my button.

```
class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;


  const VideoPlayerWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.videoPlayerController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerWidgetState createState() => _VideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

class _VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      //fullScreenByDefault: true,
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      autoInitialize: true,
      autoPlay: true,
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ],
      errorBuilder: (context, e) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('Some error occurred'),
        );
      },
    );
    _chewieController.addListener(() {
      if (_chewieController.isFullScreen) {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        ]);
      } else {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]);
      }
    });
    widget.videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
      if (widget.videoPlayerController.value.position ==
          widget.videoPlayerController.value.duration) {
        print('video completed.');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[               
              SizedBox(height: length.height * 0.2),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: length.height * 0.2),
            ],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: (widget.videoPlayerController.value.position ==
                      widget.videoPlayerController.value.duration)
                  ? true
                  : false,
              child: FlatButton(child: Text('Completed'),
                        onPressed:()=> Navigatior.of(context).pop()),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't disable/enable buttons in Flutter by using `AbsorbPointer`, you just have to set the button's `onPressed` callback to `null`:

```dart
FlatButton(
  child: Text('Completed'),
  onPressed: hasVideoFinished ? () => Navigatior.of(context).pop() : null,
),
```

Define a boolean like `hasVideoFinished` somewhere in your code and call `setState()`.